# Way to count number of digits in a Bignum

Tags: ruby, bignum

I am writing a ruby method as follows:

```
def build_array(word)
  word_copy = word
  array = []
  length = word_copy.length
  for i in 1..length do
    array[i] = word_copy % 10
    word_copy = word_copy/10;
  end
 puts array
end
```

I would like to create an iterator which counts from 1 to the number of digits in a `Bignum`.

`Bignum.length` is not valid ruby. Alternatively, is there a way to bust up a `Bignum` into an array of its constituent digits (Which is what I am trying to implement).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `num.to_s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert it to String and count its size

```
b = 2_999_999_000_000_000
p b.class
#=> Bignum
p b.to_s.size
#=> 16
p b.to_s.split("").map(&:to_i)
#=> [2, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `b.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)` saves a few strokes and reduces line noise.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = 424723894070784320891478329472334238899
Math.log10(x).floor + 1 # => 39
```

or

```
Math.log10(x + 1).ceil # => 39
```

Comment: And it's faster too! Although, way less obvious, if I may.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I thought this was the most straightforward. I cannot think of a more obvious answer than this.

Comment: maybe it's just me being bad at maths.